# How to make this into a checkbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I have a view as such:

```
@model Tuple<LocApp.Models.Location, LocApp.Models.Service>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Location</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item1.name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item1.name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item1.name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item1.active)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item1.active)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item1.active)
        </div>

       @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Item2.id)


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and the line: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Item2.id)` IMO is suppose to go through and for every service in  the database create a check box based on the id so I can then save the id. How ever, apparently I must pass in a boolean value? the only one I have is `model.Item2.active`

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CheckBoxes can only have boolean states: Checked or Unchecked. Your model must set a checkbox state by using a boolean value of true or false. If you want your checkbox to act as the mechanism for saving an Id to your database, you need to write business logic for checking if the checkbox is checked on the controller action. If the checkbox is checked, write the Id, otherwise don't write the Id.

Comment: OK, I understand about the business logic side, so I am assuming I must create the checked bool in my model?

Comment: You will need to add a checked state to your model if you are loading checkbox states from your database. Otherwise, you can just loop over the form values and see if a particular checkbox was checked on the form POST.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a bool model.Item1.checked (or active, enabled, etc), then use that instead of model.Item1.id, it will keep track of whether the flag is on or off for that item.

Then when they POST the form you can loop through (or use LINQ) all the items and save the id for each one that has .checked = true.

Comment: ok. That works, and If I can expand on this a tad bit, I have 6 or seven services and I only get one check box.... is this something for another question or can you answer that too?